# Factorization of permutations on a triple Cartesian product of a set

Tags: permutations

Let $X$ be a finite set, let's say the numbers from 1 to $N$. We consider permutations on $X^3$, which we can also regard as a bijective map $U: X^3\to X^3$. We say that $U$ is factorizable if there exist bijective maps $A,B,C$, all of them $X^2\to X^2$, such that
$$U_{123}=C_{23}B_{13}A_{12}$$
Here the notation is such that $U$ acts on the triple product, and 1, 2, 3 stand for the components, and for example $A_{12}$ acts on the first two components only, whereas it leaves the third component invariant. It is clear that not every U is factorizable, because the number of possibilities for $U$ is $(N^3)!$, whereas the number of factorizable maps is limited by $((N^2)!)^3$, which is smaller.

**Questions**: Are there easy conditions to check, if I want to find out whether $U$ is factorizable? What would be a good algorithm for factorization? Brute force check works of course (we can check all possibilities for $A, B, C$ and see whether their product reproduces $U$), but this is not efficient if $N$ starts to increase.

**Motivation**: The question comes from physics, this is some simple model for more complicated interactions. We would have three particles on a line, each of them having an internal label with $N$ possibilities. When particles get exchanged, the labels can change, but only for those particles who meet at the same spot. In this interpretation, a factorized permutation corresponds to factorized scattering of particles in a process, where the leftmost and rightmost particles get exchanged, while the middle one stays in place. Factorizability means that there is no true three-particle interaction in the system, just two-particle scattering.

**Remark:** This question was [first posted to math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4496594/factorization-of-permutations-on-a-triple-cartesian-product-of-a-set), but there was no reply in a few weeks.

Comment: Although it doesn't answer it, I can't help thinking of the [Kolmogorov–Arnol'd representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov–Arnold_representation_theorem) when reading this question.

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting, I did not know about it.

Answer (score 1):

I claim that one can (at least usually) compute a factorization of $U$ as $C_{2,3}B_{1,3}A_{1,2}$ in a reasonable amount of time as long as a factorization exists. My sort of algorithm for factorizing $U$ may be far from the most efficient algorithm for factorizing $U$, but the idea behind my algorithm is quite simple and applies to a vast collection of problems.

If $Z$ is a finite set, then define the Hamming distance metric $d$ on the
symmetric group $S_Z$ by letting $d(f,g)=|\{x\in X:f(x)\neq g(x)\}|$.

Given a bijection $U:X^3\rightarrow X^3$, define a loss function
$L_U:(S_{X^2})^3\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ by letting
$L_U(A,B,C)=d(U,C_{2,3}B_{1,3}A_{1,2})$ where $d$ denotes the Hamming distance between two permutations.

One can then use evolutionary computation to find $A,B,C$ such that the loss $L_U(A,B,C)$ is minimized, and once we get $L_U(A,B,C)=0$, we have
$U=C_{2,3}B_{1,3}A_{1,2}$.

A reasonable choice of a mutation operator in this evolutionary computation will be to first select a permutation $D$ from the three permutations $A,B,C$ and then replace $D$ with $D\cdot(a,b)$ where $a,b$ are selected uniformly at random from the collection of all pairs $a,b\in X$ such that $a\neq b$ (i.e. we differ $D$ by a transposition).

Comment: Thank you, interesting idea!

Comment: If people think an answer is interesting (and correct; it is not too hard to program a computer to verify yourself that this works), they usually upvote instead of just comment.

Comment: For me it is ok to give an upvote. I did not give it before, because your post does not answer the question. It is an idea, which might work very often, but you do not demonstrate (you might not even think) that it always works. I would need something which works for all inputs. --- I have never programmed an iterative algorithm like this, so I don't have experience with it. But perhaps we will try this at one time.